# jLabel.setText issue in my stopwatch program

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a stopwatch in Java and have had some success. It will print to the shell if I do

`System.out.println(min+":"+sec+":"+millisec);`

But, if I do

`timerLbl.setText(min+":"+sec+":"+millisec);`

nothing happens.

```
public class rubiksTimer extends javax.swing.JFrame {
static int scrambleImage = 1;
static int timesImage = 1;
static int start = 0;
static int stop1 =0;
static int millisec =0;
static int sec =0;
static int min =0;
static int press =1;

Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    public void run() {
    millisec++;
    if (millisec>9) {
        millisec = 0;
        sec++;
    }
    if (sec>59){
        sec=0;
        min++;
    }
    timerLbl.setText(min+":"+sec+":"+millisec);

    }
};

public void start(){
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,1000,100);


}
```

Comment: 1) I agree with @FastSnail -- use a Swing Timer as this won't freeze the Swing event thread or cause intermittent hard to debug threading errors like a java.util.Timer may do. 2) Also, if you want a more complete answer, you'll want to improve your question and try to ask a more complete question, including more code, best if it were a [mcve], and more explanation. 3) Some side recommendations: avoid over-use of static fields and methods as you appear to be doing as that increases the interconnectedness of your code (its cyclomatic complexity) increasing risk for bugs.

Comment: Also you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Also, get rid of all the static variable. This is an indication of a poorly designed class.

Comment: Also, read up a bit about Swing, and the event-driven programming model in Oracle Java trails. It is essential to understand the difference of the console-based applications and the GUI applications. The console apps run linear, while the GUI apps run by reacting to events.